# triangle not being shown in basic webgl program

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl

i am trying to create a simple webgl program that draws a triangle with some gradient.

here us the program.

1. first, I created the canvas with `webgl` context .
2. created vertex shader & fragment shaders.
3. compiled vertex shaders & fragment shaders into a program.
4. set relevant data buffers & passed `vertex` & `color` data in those.
   but is doesn't shows anything even in the console i cannot find any error

   ```
   var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
   canvas.width = window.innerWidth
   canvas.height = window.innerHeight
   document.body.appendChild(canvas)

   //craete a canavs webgl context as a base to draw upon
   var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl')
   //  clear canvas with any color you want
   gl.clearColor(0.75, 0.85, 0.8, 1.0)
   gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)


   // webgl pipeline need 2 shaders 1) vertex shader & fragment shader
   // crate a vertex shader & compile it
   var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER)
   gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, [
     'attribute vec4 aVertexColor;',
     'varying lowp vec4 vColor;',

     'attribute vec2 position;',
     'void main() {',
       'gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);',
        'vColor = aVertexColor;',

     '}'
   ].join('\n'))
   gl.compileShader(vertexShader)

       if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
           console.error('ERROR compiling vertex shader!', gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
       }


   // create a fragment shader & compile it 
   var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER)
   gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, [
     'varying lowp vec4 vColor;',
     'void main() {',
       'gl_FragColor = vColor;',
     '}'
   ].join('\n'))
   gl.compileShader(fragmentShader)

       if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
           console.error('ERROR compiling fragment shader!', gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
       }


   //craete a program that will be offloaded to the GPU
   var program = gl.createProgram()

   //attach vertex shader & fragment shaders to the the program
   gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader)
   gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader)

   //link program
   gl.linkProgram(program)

       gl.linkProgram(program);
       if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
           console.error('ERROR linking program!', gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
       }
       gl.validateProgram(program);
       if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.VALIDATE_STATUS)) {
           console.error('ERROR validating program!', gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
       }

   //define vertex positions as float32 array elemnets
   var vertices = new Float32Array([
     -0.5, -0.5,
     0.5,  -0.5,
     0.0,   0.5
   ])




   //create  buffer where data will be stored
   var buffer = gl.createBuffer()
   // mark the given buffer as current/active buffer
   gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)
   //add data to the active buffer
   gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW)



   const colors = [
       1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,    // white
       1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,    // red
       0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,    // green
     ];

   const colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
   gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
   gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);



   //tell webgl to use the progr that we created
   gl.useProgram(program)

   program.aVertexColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'aVertexColor'),
   gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.aVertexColor,4,gl.FLOAT,false,0,0);
   gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.aVertexColor);


   //get location of the attribute `position` defined in our shader program
   program.position = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position')
   gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.position)
   gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)


   gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.length / 2)
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in binding data to `position` shader attribute. `vertexAttribPointer` binds a buffer currently bound to `ARRAY_BUFFER` target. When you make a call `gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)` the `colorBuffer` is bound. So WebGL tries to read positions from it. If you add `gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)` before that call, a [triangle's rendered as expected](http://jsbin.com/rodosogifa/edit?js,output).

Comment: thanks but then previous call `gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)` is not required right? there are no w2 same calls to `gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)` in program

Comment: It is required, because after it you call `bufferData`, which works on currently bound buffer object too. Only one GL object can be bound to a target. Then every GL call that references that target (like `bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, /* ... */)` references `ARRAY_BUFFER` target) will work on the bound object. If you remove find `bindBuffer` call, there'll be no object bound to the target, and `bufferData` call will fail.